# React curried arrow function in event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does react know to provide the event as a second argument in the code below?

```
const clickMe = (parameter) => (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Do something
}
    
<button onClick={clickMe(someParameter)} />
```

Does it generate this to:

```
<button onClick={(event) => clickMe(someParameter)(event)} />
```

Or how does it work?
Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a React issue, it's just how JavaScript works. `clickMe` returns a function which accepts one `event` argument. It's that function that's used as the listener for `onClick`. And when `onClick` is called it passes the event as the first argument to that function.

Comment: Agree to @Andy to add to this. Its not technically a currying but a block of currying which is Higher order Functions. Basically a function returns a function (or accept functions as argument)

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: But the first argument is `parameter` and not `event` so how does it handle it as a second argument?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help explain it a little better.

[Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) are functions that carry the information (variables etc.) from their local environment with them when they're returned.

I'll work this example without arrow functions as they can be a little deceiving.

```js
// `multplyBy` accepts a number as its argument
// It returns a new function that "remembers" that number
// when it's returned. But that new function *also*
// accepts a number
function multiplyBy(n) {
  return function(n2) {
    return n2 * n;
  }
}

// So `multiplyBy(5)` returns a new function
// which we assign to the variable `five`
const five = multiplyBy(5);

// And when we call `five` with a number we get
// the result of calling 5 * 10.
console.log(five(10));
```

If you substitute `multiplyBy(n)` with `clickMe(n)` you'll see that you'll get a new function that gets used by the click listener, and the first argument of that function will always be the event.

Answer (score 0):

Clickme variable in your code is a function which has return is function e => {...}. So when you specify like this:

```
<button onClick={clickMe(someParameter)} />
```

it is equivalent to

```
<button onClick={e => {...} />
```

which is basic form of a event handler in react